# Data is not showing accurate in Google Analytics funnel

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

How do I track my correct figure from funnel, I had create 2 funnel and the path are different from each other. But when I check the data in funnel visualization the numbers are showing same, below are my experience-

Lets say that there are two ways to fill the form and make the conversion:

```
/homepage
/recharge
/thankyou
```

and another:

```
/homepage
/myaccount
/recharge
/thankyou
```

The second step is different in the two cases.

And data I got

```
/homepage - 220000
/recharge - 40000
/thankyou - 40000
```

and another:

```
/homepage - 220000
/myaccount - 40000
/recharge - 40000
/thankyou - 40000
```

How is it possible if I had created 2 different funnel, if I check any date it's show same data. From my understanding my account and recharge page data should be different.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

Goal funnels only affect the goal funnel report.
All other goal reports will record a goal conversion if someone reaches the goal destination URL.

With funnels, only the first step can be marked as a required step, in which case, entrances lower in the funnel will not be shown in the funnel chart, and only those site visitors that fulfill the first step will show as a funnel conversion.

If the first step is not marked as required, then that is not taken into account with the funnel conversions, and any site visitor reaching the goal destination URL will show as a funnel conversion.

In this instance, even if you have marked the first step as being required, because both funnels are using the same first step and same goal destination URL, then they are both going to show the same number of conversions.

Sometimes it is better to use a single goal and then use sequence segments to access more granular conversion data.
https://www.bounteous.com/insights/2016/04/04/more-accurate-conversion-data-sequence-segments/